# Magento 2 How Generate Unique Widget phtml Class Names

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have developed a widget. It has a block class which sets the front-end template. I have this function which generate unique class names.

```
public function getClassName()
{
    $class = "mywidget-widget-" . md5(uniqid("mywidget-widget"));
    return $class;
}
```

When I call that function on the front-end phtml file for multiple widgets of the same type, it always returns the first unique key to be generated. Why does this happen?

```
$block->getClassName()
```

Comment: FYI, you can use `getUniqueHash('mywidget-widget')` from `\Magento\Framework\Math\Random` to generate a unique hash from a string

Comment: Same thing happens, only the first generated key is being used for all the other instances of the widget.